# C# Deserialize text in XML mixed content as custom object?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Is it possible to have an XML, one of which elements has mixed content, and deserialize the text in the mixed element as a custom object instead of as `string`?

I tried this:

```
    [XmlText(typeof(textType))]
    [XmlElement("query", typeof(templateBodyQuery))]
    [XmlElement("expand", typeof(expandType))]
    [XmlElement("insert", typeof(expandTypeInsert))]
    public object[] Items { get; set; }
```

Expecting the text items would be serialized as `textType`, but I get an `'textType' cannot be used as 'xml text'` error.

This is my `textType` class:

```
public class textType
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use non primitive types for XmlText.  Also I'm not sure I understand how that xml would be structured as you can't have XmlText and XmlElements under a single node.

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
[XmlElement("textType",typeof(textType))]
[XmlElement("query", typeof(templateBodyQuery))]
[XmlElement("expand", typeof(expandType))]
[XmlElement("insert", typeof(expandTypeInsert))]
public object[] Items { get; set; }
```

which deserializes:

```
<Test>
    <textType>example</textType>
    <query>...</query>
    <expand>...</expand>
</Test>
```

To a class `Test` that has a textType object at the start of the `Items` array with `Value` of "example"